Xero API - Tenant missing on the /connections endpoint of the API
We have a Xero Certified app that's been working great for the last couple of years.
There is one user that logs in and can connect/ disconnect apps as required and then there is a background service that gets all tenants (connected apps) by hitting the /connections endpoint of the Xero API. Once we have the list of tenants we can create invoices, etc.
This process works very well in general and we have 98 tenants connected to our certified app.
The problem is that all of the sudden, two weeks ago, one tenant dissapeared from the list of tenants we get from the /connections endpoint. We tried disconnecting the tenant/organisation and connecting it again, but no matter what we do, it does not show up in the list of tenants.
What can we do to troubleshoot this? Are there any conditions for a tenant to not be retrieved in this endpoint? What things can we check in the missing account to make sure it shows up as expected?
Thanks
We tried disconnecting the tenant/organisation and connecting it again, which is pretty much the only thing we can try at this stage, but no matter what we do, it does not show up in the list of tenants.
